# Understanding Node.js use cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

Trying to understand using node.js for a web applications.

Are there basically 2 major uses cases, i.e.:

1. The entire system is written in node, so you have functions for login, logout, password recover, and whatever else the web app does.  All of this is written in javascript?
2. You use node.js only for sending the client updates, to have a real-time effect on the app.  But the rest of the application is written in e.g. rails or django

Please tell me if I understand this correctly:

In terms of other technologies used with node.js, you tend to see people using node.js as the backend server, socket.io on the client side to establish a cross-browser long running ajax call library, and then you might use backbone.js for your client mvc pattern.

Is this right?

Comment: Node.js is a JavaScript runtime system.  You can use it for anything you like; anything you might do with Python, Java, C++, or any other programming system. It may be better or worse suited for particular tasks, but it's a general-purpose system nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

Basically speaking, it is just a tool to run javascript code server side. What you do with it is up to you. Many are using it as a complementary system since it's relatively new, but it's perfectly possible to run an standalone app with node.js.

It's said to be particularly good at handling concurrent connections, which is why it is often recommended to handle real-time jobs within an app, but there is no "obligation" so to speak to use it for this specific use case, it's just one thing you can do.

As with everything, the best way to understand it is to use it, so don't be afraid to play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use case for Node js as we are using in our Application
Skype like voice & video chat  on chrome browser using node js